# travel a subway

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is there any suggestion for the phrase: I travel a subway to work, and one more sentence,"Ｉtravel to work by subway."  Are they both the same meaning?  May I say, "travel a subway equals to take a subway"?

Comment: You ***take*** the subway - idiomatically, you don't normally [transitively] ***travel*** it.

Comment: No, "travel" is not transitive. You cannot say "I travel a subway". You can say "I take the subway", if you want. Please check out our sister site dedicated to helping people learn English as a foreign language, [ELL.se].

Comment: @Dan Bron: [Why this is (h)ELL, nor are we out of it!](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/35132.html) :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Welp, I am totally stealing that for a meta-question title about improving question quality around here :)

Comment: @Dan Bron: I've always liked that line from Marlowe (partly the sentiment itself, but partly just the "quirky" use of ***nor***), but I never thought I'd get such a chance to riff off it here! Do I get extra brownie points for improving the quality of *comments?*

Comment: "I travel a subway to work" sounds vert strange to me, just IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You would express this by saying:

> I take the subway to work.

-or-

> I ride the subway to work.

"Travel" typically implies a longer distance than subways cover.

Answer (score 0):

*Travel X* means *travel through X*, not *travel by X*.   You can travel places, but you travel *by* vehicles.

If X in *travel X* is a vehicle, a listener/speaker will likely assume you mean *travel by X* but it will sound jarring.

"Travelling a subway" would only make complete sense if you are exploring through tunnels of a hopefully inactive or abandoned subway.